# Github Push to multiple repository

Tags: angular, github, visual-studio-code

I have an Angular Admin Panel. In this, I have a lot of common files in it means User forms, UserRights, Login Form, profile, change password, settings, etc. So I want to push these common files in one Github Repository and the remaining files in another reporsitory. I want to use these common files in an upcoming project. So my aim is any changes in the common files will affect all the projects. How to do this in Github with VSCode.

Comment: You can add the other repo as a new remote in git and then you can run the `git push` command 2 times one for `origin` and then for `new_origin`. Also you can set an alias to do both the push in a single command.

Comment: Maybe git modules

Comment: Or use shared part as a library project

Comment: Or use monorepo, which is my choice of work